# Picard group of a cone over the elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group

Let E be an smooth elliptic curve in a projective plane.

Suppose that X is the projective cone over E in a projective space of dimension three.

What is the Picard group of X ?

Answer (score 6):

The restriction map $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^3) \rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ is an isomorphism. This is actually true for any cone provided the depth at the vertex is $>1$: see Proposition 3.10 in Jaffe's *Space curves which are the intersection of a cone with another surface*, Duke Math. J. 57, no. 3, 859-876 (1988).